# OCR gives wrong output

Tags: python, ocr, opencv, python-tesseract

I'm currently busy with a project that reads on screen text using Python from a FIFA 20 gameplay video.
I take every x frames a 'screenshot' so I can use pytesseract for the OCR.
I have a snippet from FIFA 20 gameplay with the words/number I would like to extract (the time, the score, and both the teamnames).

The only problem is that I want to crop the image so I have the match-time, team name, score, opponent name as different pictures so I can use OCR to read each image because the picture as a whole doesn't get picked up well with pytesseract.
I already tried some filters, edge detection (cv2.Canny()) etc. but I didn't get the right output I needed. I had some weird characters because of the gap between the time and teamnames/score, and some weird characters from the score (because of the black background?).

So my question is, what would be the best approach to solve this problem?
Is there a way to make an adaptive crop thing, where it cuts out both team names, the time, and the score as different pictures so I can use OCR seperate on them? Or is there some other way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

[Data I want to retrieve from image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vr6u8.png)

Edit: Right I tried making a mask by filtering every colour except the yellow-ish colour for the teamnames by using this code:

```
roi_teamnames = image[55:90, 120:900]
roi_teamnames = cv2.cvtColor(roi_teamnames, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
lower = np.array([0, 25, 147], dtype="uint8")
upper = np.array([32, 255, 255], dtype="uint8")
roi_teamnames = cv2.inRange(roi_teamnames, lower, upper)
cv2.imshow("Teamnames",roi_teamnames)
```

This gives me a pretty good result I can work with (see link).

[Result with mask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fh2kV.png)

But now is the question, is there a way to auto-detect the white spaces so I can crop the image in 2 different images each containing the different names?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, add your code attempts to the question. It may help another visitors to propose a working solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code to extract teams names, times, scores from the image you gave above. There are a few assumptions (see the code) that may be adequate... or not. You'll have to try.
The code:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageOps
import pytesseract
from pytesseract import Output

img = Image.open('image.png')
gray=ImageOps.grayscale(img)

# We ASSUME teams names are always in capital letters, plus the following signs: "-","/" and "." (add more if needed)
letters=pytesseract.image_to_data(gray, output_type=Output.DICT, config='-c tessedit_char_whitelist=\ -/.ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ' )

# For the numbers (time, scores): 
# We ASSUME time and scores are always in light caracters on a dark background. So we work on the color inverted image because 
# light caracters on black background are not properly recognized.
# We ASSUME times and scores are made of digits, plus ":" and "-" 
numbers=pytesseract.image_to_data(ImageOps.invert(gray), output_type=Output.DICT, config='-c tessedit_char_whitelist=:-0123456789' )


# Working on numbers:
conf_numbers=[x for x in numbers['conf']] # confidence indice for detection
data_num=[]
for i in range(0,len(conf_numbers)):
    if int(conf_numbers[i])>-1:  # contains numbers
        data_num.append(numbers['text'][i])

time=data_num[0]
score=data_num[1]


# Working on letters:
conf_letters=[int(item) for item in letters['conf']]
words=[]
for i in range(0,len(conf_letters)):
    if conf_letters[i]>75:   # confidence threshold (0 - 100%) Note: You can print these values to have a feeling about the needed threshold
        words.append(letters['text'][i])
    else:
        words.append('*')
words.append('*')


# Assembling words to make teams names:
Flag=0
teams_names=[]
team=''
for i in range(0, len(words)):    
    
    if Flag==1 and not(words[i]=='*'):       
        team=team+words[i]
        
    if Flag==1 and words[i]=='*':
        teams_names.append(team)
        team=''
        Flag=0

    if Flag==0 and not(words[i]=='*'):
        Flag=1
        team=words[i]+' '
team_A=teams_names[0]
team_B=teams_names[1]

print('Team A: ',team_A)
print('Team B: ',team_B)
print('Time: ',time)
print('Score: ',score)
```

and the output is:

```
Team A:  WOLVES FIFILZA
Team B:  FNATIC TEKKZ
Time:  71:26
Score:  0-1
```

Best regards,

Stéphane

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the code that i had found somewhere in the stackoverflow to detect text in an image this might be helpful for you **

```
import cv2

# Load image, grayscale, Gaussian blur, adaptive threshold
image = cv2.imread(r'E:\tesseract.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (9,9), 0)
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(blur,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV,11,30)

# Dilate to combine adjacent text contours
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (9,9))
dilate = cv2.dilate(thresh, kernel, iterations=4)

# Find contours, highlight text areas, and extract ROIs
cnts = cv2.findContours(dilate, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]

ROI_number = 0
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area > 100:
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (36,255,12), 3)
cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('dilate', dilate)
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey()
```